# How to convert Format for Date and Time in Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch 2 I have a model with the following fields, DateTimeStart if rendered in a List it shows in this format

```
Mon Feb 11 2013 11:55:00 GMT +100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

I need to create another field (`DateTimeStartConverted`) based on `DateTimeStart` 
I need to convert such date in a more short format using 'Y-m-d'.

Printing the result of DateTimeStartConverted in my conversion method it does not display any result (no errors has been throw).

Any idea how to fix it?

```
{
   name: 'DateTimeStart',
   type: 'date',
   dateFormat: 'MS'
}, {
   name: 'DateTimeStartConverted',
   type: 'date',
   convert: function(value, record){
       var jsonDate  = record.get('DateTimeStart'); 
       return  Ext.Date.format(jsonDate, 'Y-m-d');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to display the date properly in a list item template, then you can use the `:date()` function within your template:

```
{
  xtype: 'list',
  ...
  itemTpl: '<p>Date display test - {DateTimeStart:date("m/d/Y")}</p>',
  ...
}
```

As for your convert function, it looks sound, but what do you get for the `value` and `record` arguments? Knowing those values would help a lot.